# 43 men in 7 group meetings problem

Tags: combinations

We have 43 men. They meet each other in 7-men groups. Each of them must see other man (in left 42 men) only once.
Describe all combinations how they can meet each other.

Answer (score 1):

If it was 13 men in groups of 4, difference set {0, 1, 3, 9}.
If it was 21 men in groups of 5, difference set {0, 3, 4, 9, 11}.
If it was 31 men in groups of 6, difference set {0, 4, 10, 23, 24, 26}.
If it was 57 men in groups of 8, difference set {0, 1, 6, 15, 22, 26, 45, 55}.

There isn't a handy difference set of length 7.

The best known answer has [43 meetings](http://www.ccrwest.org/cover/t_pages/t2/k7/C_43_7_2.html) before a repeat.

Comment: could please tell me more details. what you  mean in difference set?

Comment: also in this list i see that number 1 has met number 21 twice in row 5 and 7. so its not correct i think

Comment: The first difference set gives:  
{{0, 1, 3, 9}, {1, 2, 4, 10}, {2, 3, 5, 11}, {3, 4, 6, 12},    
{4, 5, 7, 0}, {5, 6, 8, 1}, {6, 7, 9, 2}, {7, 8, 10, 3}, {8, 9, 11, 4}, 
{9, 10, 12, 5}, {10, 11, 0, 6}, {11, 12, 1, 7}, {12, 0, 2, 8}}
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_set  
Looks like http://www.ccrwest.org/cover.html might have an error for that one.

Comment: The La Jolla covering design repository has been migrated by Dan Gordon to [his new site](https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/), so it might be a good time to update your link.